# Create a JSON keys in an object in Python

Tags: python

I load a json file and I want to modify it in Python.
I want a create a key like this:

```
"key": {
   "item1": "car",
   "item2: "truck"
   }
```

When I try with:

```
for d in data:
   i["key"]["item1"] = []
   i["key"]["item2"] = []
I have a `KeyError: "key"`
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the raw input data file?

Comment: Please paste the full code ?

Comment: What's `data`? What's `i`?

Comment: Your example data is missing curly brackets at the beginning and end.

Comment: What's wrong? - I think the question is wrong. It is not clear what you want and what you have

Answer (score 1):

The given "json"-Example is not proper json.
Despite the missing quote-marks after "item2", the whole text-block has to be encased into curly braces, like such:

```
{
"key": {
   "item1": "car",
   "item2": "truck"
   }
}
```

You can use this [jsonlinter](https://jsonlint.com/) to find out, if your json-files are correctly defined.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a properly formatted json for this to work. This is a multi-dimensional dictionary format and you need to set up each layer before moving into the next.

Here is a basic example:

```
i = {}
i['keys'] = {}
i['keys']['item1'] = 'car'
i['keys']['item2'] = 'truck'
```

This will return:

```
{
"key": {
   "item1": "car",
   "item2": "truck"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Python treats JSON Objects as dictionaries. Therefore you have to load the json string.

```
import json

json_str = {
    "key_1": "value_1",
    "key_2": "value_2"
}

json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
```

You can access a value by using the specific key as an index

```
print(json_dict["key_1"])
>> value_1
```

Iterating directly over a dictionary will result in it's keys.

```
for item in key:
    print(item)

>> item1, item2
```